env.py does not provide a MetaData object or sequence of o bjects to the context
The block of code this error is related to:

target_metadata = [users_metadata, posts_metadata]

I've already have imported my models like that:
from models.users import metadata as users_metadata
from models.posts import metadata as posts_metadata

The related code for the posts.py & users.py:
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()


For solving that error I used different variations of target_metadata, but they didn't work:
target_metadata = None target_metadata = [users.metadata, posts.metadata]
